# Flask Hello World error

Tags: python, flask

I installed Python, Flask following these articles in CentOS 6.6

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o/wiki/Installing-python-2.7-on-centos-6.3.-Follow-this-sequence-exactly-for-centos-machine-only

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Now When I am running hello.py i.e

```
    from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

Is there anything that needs to be done to run Flask beside that is provided in those documentation?

Thanks

Comment: /opt/myproject/venv/bin/pip install Flask

Comment: It points to the correct Python python
Python 3.4.0 (default, May  9 2015, 18:46:59) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit();

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, so probably you haven't installed Flask globally.

Have you installed through sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv or through easy_install ?

Comment: I installed through easy_install i.e sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install virtualenv

Comment: yeah, virtualenv is a bummer sometimes. Try to include '-g' in the instalation command, 99% sure it's a PATH problem

Comment: sudo /opt/myproject/venv/bin/pip install Flask

Comment: sudo /usr/local/bin/virtualenv -g venv
[sudo] password for web: 
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

virtualenv: error: no such option: -g

Comment: Still the same issue with using -p option as well. sudo /usr/local/bin/virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python venv
[sudo] password for web: 
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

Comment: not sure about python 2 but this http://techarena51.com/index.php/how-to-install-python-3-and-flask-on-linux/ is how i installed with python 3

Answer (score 0):

I had my **hello.py** in `/opt/myproject/flask/hello.py`
I had my **venv** in `/opt/myproject/flask/venv`

In `/opt/myproject/flask` I was doing `. venv/bin/activate` and running the python **hello.py**.

But once I went to `/opt/myproject/flask/venv` and did `. bin/activate`
and came back to `/opt/myproject/flask` and ran python **hello.py**
everything came out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously as mentioned above you haven't installed flask yet.

Essentially if you create too many projects, then use virtualenvwrapper where you can list your environments by executing the command:

```
workon
```

Access your env like this:

```
workon myenv
```

Think of any project to be encapsulated from other project by wrapping all the packages inside a virtual environment and this env needs to be activated before running the project. Any module/package you import in your project should be preinstalled inside your environment by using this example below:

```
pip install Flask
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

And you can list your packages inside your environment by executing this command:

```
pip list
```

Usually you should have all the packages **added** to your **requirements.txt** to keep track on things and make it easy to install from scratch by executing this command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Follow these simple steps and you'll be on the safe side always!

Happy coding,
J.